# LINQ with Group, Join and Where Easy in SQL not in LINQ?

Tags: performance, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I have trouble understand how to translate SQL into LINQ. I would like to do the following but can't figure out how to get the Group By to work

```
var query = from s in Supplier
            join o in Offers on s.Supp_ID equals o.Supp_ID
            join p in Product on o.Prod_ID equals p.Prod_ID
            where s.City == "Chicago"
            group s by s.City into Results
            select new { Name = Results.Name };
```

I just need to do something simple like display the product name of this simple query, how does the group by work with joins and a where?

Comment: Can you use navigation properties like `Supplier.Offers` and `Offer.Products`?

Answer (score 3):

You haven't provided classes so I **assumed** that they are like below:

```
    public class Supplier
    {
        public int SupplierID { get; set; }

        public string SuppierName { get; set; }

        public string City { get; set; }
    }


    public class Product
    {
        public int ProductID { get; set; }

        public string ProductName { get; set; }
    }

    public class Offer
    {
        public int SupplierID { get; set; }

        public int ProductID { get; set; }
    }
```

Then I added data for *testing*:

```
    List<Supplier> supplierList = new List<Supplier>()
                                 {
                                     new Supplier() { SupplierID = 1, SuppierName = "FirstCompany", City = "Chicago"},
                                     new Supplier() { SupplierID = 2, SuppierName = "SecondCompany", City = "Chicago"},
                                     new Supplier() { SupplierID = 3, SuppierName = "ThirdCompany", City = "Chicago"},
                                 };


    List<Product> productList = new List<Product>()
                                {
                                    new Product() { ProductID = 1, ProductName = "FirstProduct" },
                                    new Product() { ProductID = 2, ProductName = "SecondProduct" },
                                    new Product() { ProductID = 3, ProductName = "ThirdProduct" }
                                };

    List<Offer> offerList = new List<Offer>()
                             {
                                 new Offer() { SupplierID = 1, ProductID = 2},
                                 new Offer() { SupplierID = 2, ProductID = 1},
                                 new Offer() { SupplierID = 2, ProductID = 3}
                             };
```

If you want to show names of suppliers whiches products have been offered then your LINQ query should be as this:

```
    IEnumerable<string> result = from supplier in supplierList
                                 join offer in offerList on supplier.SupplierID equals offer.SupplierID
                                 join product in productList on offer.ProductID equals product.ProductID
                                 where supplier.City == "Chicago"
                                 group supplier by supplier.SuppierName into g
                                 select g.Key;
```

You can see if correct names have been selected:

```
    foreach (string supplierName in result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(supplierName);
    }
```

It must give following result:

**FirstCompany**

**SecondCompany**

Comment: Quite thorough. Why not add the result data to your answer?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
   var query = from s in Supplier
                    join o in Offers on s.Supp_ID equals o.Supp_ID
                    join p in Product on o.Prod_ID equals p.Prod_ID
                    where s.City == "Chicago"
                    group s 
                    by new {s.City, s.Name} //added this
                    into Results
                    select new { Name = Results.Key.Name };
```

Answer (score 0):

You group `s` (Supplier) by `s.City`. The result of this is an `IGrouping<City, Supplier>`. I.e. only `City` and `Supplier` are within reach after the grouping: for each City you get an `IEnumerable<Supplier>` of its suppliers (which will be multiplied by the joins, by the way).

Since you also have the condition `where s.City == "Chicago"` grouping by city is of no use. There is only one city. So I think you may as well do something like this:

```
from s in Supplier
join o in Offers on s.Supp_ID equals o.Supp_ID
join p in Product on o.Prod_ID equals p.Prod_ID
where s.City == "Chicago"
select new { 
                City = s.City.Name, 
                Supplier = s.Name,
                Product = p.Name,
                ...
            };
```